# Array subtraction in PowerShell

Tags: linq, powershell

I have an array of objects:

```
$people= @()
foreach ($person in $databaseOfGuests)
{
   $people += @{ "FirstName"=$person.FirstName; "LastName"=$person.LastName } 
}
```

Now I want to remove duplicates from `$people`, is it possible to do this in PowerShell? Something like:

```
$people = $people | Select -Uniq
```

I have two arrays `$people1` and `$people2`, I need to get array of all people that are in `$people1` but not in the `$people2` and vise versa. Something like:

```
$peopleInPeople1ButNotInPeople2 = $people1.Substruct($people2)
$peopleInPeople2ButNotInPeople1 = $people2.Substruct($people1)
```

Is it possible to do it in one line in PS?

Comment: You should go `$people += $person` instead. Then you can compare using [`-notin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#-notin) operator

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$people1 | ? {$_ -notin $people2}
```

or you can filter by property, like firstname or lastname:

```
$people1 | ? {$_.Firstname -notin $people2.Firstname}
```

- the `-notin` operator is available on PS3 and above, for lower versions you can use `-notcontains`

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to fall back to the .NET Framework and use LINQ. But it turns out that the PowerShell syntax is pretty ugly:

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]] $people1, [object[]] $people2)
```

(I'm not sure why the `object[]` casts are necessary, but without them PowerShell throws an "Cannot find an overload for "Except" and the argument count: "2"" exception.)

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic PowerShell would be:

```
$people1 | Where-Object { $people2 -notcontains $_ }
```

Comment: I tried this way and it didn't work for me, maybe because I add new objects to the array in a wrong way - `+= @{ "FirstName"=$person.FirstName; "LastName"=$person.LastName }`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other good answers, following code depicts all SET operation on PowerShell Arrays:

```
#Union - Subtraction - Minus:
$a = (1,2,3,4)
$b = (1,2,77,88)
'UNION:'
Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru -IncludeEqual                    # union
''
'INTERSECTION:'
Compare-Object $a $b -PassThru -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent  # intersection
''
'MINUS:'
'$a minus $b:'
$a | ?{$b -notcontains $_}                                      # a -minus b
'$b minus $a:'
$b | ?{$a -notcontains $_}                                      # b -minus a
```

HTH.